# Can't read from Vuex store in Storybook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, storybook

I'm using Storybook with `vue create`, and I'm trying to read state from the store but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at VueComponent.translations (http://localhost:6006/main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:161:26)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:86420:25)
    at Watcher.evaluate (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:86525:21)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as translations] (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:86775:17)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:84041:20)
    at Proxy.render (http://localhost:6006/main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:895:37)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:85489:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:86007:21)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:86420:25)
    at new Watcher (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.08c5b1c8a108e2d2d34c.bundle.js:86409:12)
```

My `HotDescription` component looks like:

```
<template>
    <div class="hot-description">
        <SvgIcon iconId="icon-hot" class="icon-hot"/>
        <span>{{translations.ui.hotMessage}}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'HotDescription',
    computed: {
        translations() {
            return this.$store.state.translations
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

.hot-description {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: $hot-description-color;
    padding: 2%;
    border-top: 1px solid $hot-description-border-color;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon-hot {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin: 0 3px 3px;
}
</style>
```

Inside `.storybook` I have two files:

`main.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-actions', '@storybook/addon-links'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            prependData: `@import "src/project/betpawa/vars.scss"; @import "src/project/common/mixins.scss"; @import "src/styles/styles.scss";`
          }
        }
    ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

And `preview.js`:

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/vue';

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

// Import your global components.
import HotDescription from '../src/components/HotDescription.vue';

// Install Vue plugins.
Vue.use(Vuex);

// Register global components.
Vue.component('HotDescription', HotDescription);

configure(require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/), module);
```

And then the stories (`stories/1-Button.stories.js`):

```
import Test from '../src/components/Test'
import HotDescription from '../src/components/HotDescription'

export default {
    title: 'Button',
    component: Test
}

export const C = () => ({
    components: { HotDescription },
    template: '<HotDescription />'
})
```

It's mounted in `src/main.js`:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/store'
import './js/directives'
import './js/plugins'
import './js/globalComponents'
import './js/android'
import './js/filters'
import './js/polyfills'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(Vuex)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>',
    mq: {
        isSmallest: '(max-width: 220px)',
        isVerySmall: '(max-width: 280px)',
        isXXSmall: '(max-width: 340px)',
        isXSmall: '(max-width: 380px)',
        isSmall: '(max-width: 767px)',
        isMedium: '(min-width: 768px)',
        isLarge: '(min-width: 980px)',
        isHighRes: '(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)' // , (min-resolution: 192dpi)
    }
})

export default app
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Storybook itself loads up, and components work without state, it's just anything that requires vuex doesn't work...

Comment: In your store/index.js change `export const store =` with `export default`.

Comment: Thanks @ZdravkoPernikov but doing this still gives the same error

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: Sorry, have added it!

Comment: Can you try to change the export and restart the project?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

FYI, I was able to get this working by adding the following to preview.js:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from '../src/store/store'

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
```

Comment: This hack should be official documentation, worked so well thanks man

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  After browsing the Storybook docs, I see [this](https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-vue/):

> You might be using global components or vue plugins such as vuex, in that case you’ll need to register them in this `preview.js` file

Their example code looks like this:

```
// Import Vue plugins
import Vuex from 'vuex';

// Install Vue plugins.
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

Have you done this in `preview.js`?  (Keep in mind I've never looked at Storybook before, just browsing the docs.)

---

## Original answer

The store has no default export, so that import syntax won't work.  You could grab the named export:

```
import { store } from './store'
```

Or you could change the store to use a default export:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 1
  },
})
```

Comment: That would be helpful lol. I've updated the original post Dan

Comment: The error shows that the `store` has not been registered correctly.  What happens if you `console.log(store)` after the imports in `main.js`?

Comment: I've added that console.log (updated the original post too) but it doesn't log anything to the console it seems - at least in Storybook. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No log there indicates that `main.js` is not being used at all... Check my edit after browsing the Storybook docs.

Comment: Has this been abandoned?  I'll delete the answer if it didn't help.

Comment: Hi Dan no it's not been abandoned. I'll post update in a few days

Comment: Hi @Dan, sorry for delayed response I've had other tasks to work on. I have tried what you have suggested but still getting the same error. Have updated the OP with the code

Comment: No problem.  Can you show where you mount the app and pass in the store?

Comment: Hey @Dan I've updated the OP to show where I mount and pass in the store. The vuex store works in the actual main app, it's just storybook where it fails

Comment: I'm not sure how Storybook mounts-- it looks like a 2nd app altogether-- but unless the `store` is imported into it somewhere, it's going to be undefined.  In the main app, the store is accessible through `this.$store` from components because it's passed in through `new Vue`.  There should be something similar in Storybook.

Comment: You could also try to `import store from '@/store/store'` directly inside `HotDescription` and access it using `store.state` instead of `this.$store.state`.  In fact, I would recommend trying that first if you can't get the store passed in through Storybook's mount.  The only downside to that is you have to do it in each component that uses the store, which may be no big deal.

Comment: Ideally I need to not make changes to the components themselves, and just use them as they already exist. Thanks Dan, I'm gonna leave this for today and try move forward with it tomorrow